# Adding 301 redirects wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am changing a website to wordpress, which will cause many URLs to change aswell.

1. I want to change all %20 to "-". urls can contain multiple %20
2. I want to do some regular changes to the URLs.

An example url:
http://www.example.com/download/NUMBER/name of the download.html

should be 301 redirected to:

https://www.example.com/download/naam-van-de-download/

The current htaccess states:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~downloadsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~downloadsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I figured the code to add should be:

```
Options FollowSymlinks MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~downloadsite/

# keep replacing space to hyphen until there is no space use internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,E=NOSPACE:1,DPI]

# when there is no space make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/(.*).html$ download/$2/ [L, R=301]
```

But it keeps giving me status 500 errors. 
Even if I only add this statement on any line of the current code it gives errors:

```
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)/(.*).html$ download/$2/ [L, R=301]
```

Anyone can pin point what is going wrong?

Comment: If you're getting status 500 errors, because of the `.htaccess` rules, then you should be able to use an .htaccess validator online, and / or check your Apache error logs to help nail down what's causing it.



Edit: According to http://www.htaccesscheck.com/ , you have an extra space after the "L" in `[L, R=301] `

Comment: `[L, R=301]` should be `[L,R=301]`